# Intended use case for CMake’s export() command

Tags: c++, c, cmake

CMake’s install(TARGETS) command supports specifying an export name, so that you can later use the instal(EXPORT) command to generate a cmake file to be found via some other project’s invocation of find_package().  This is useful for generating an intelligent cmake module file in a platform-independent way.

CMake also has an export() command, that generates a similar file for exporting targets directly from the build tree.

If, for example, I have a project that includes another project as a git submodule, why would I not just add the submodule project via CMake’s add_subdirectory() command?

My question is this:
If the export() command is not intended for situations like the above (git submodules, or something equivalent), what is it intended for?  If it is intended for the above situation, why is it superior to add_subdirectory()?

Comment: if you included the other project as a git submodule you could of course just `add_subdirectory`. However this would create a very tight coupling between your project and the version of the library in the submodule. 
This would for me (for example) rule out your project as a candidate for inclusion into mine.

Comment: Fair enough, but if the depended-on project is not included as a submodule, and if it uses the export() command to generate a FindMyLib.cmake file in it’s build tree, how is the dependent project supposed to know where to find the build tree(so it can find the file that imports all the targets from the depended-on project)?

Comment: @SumDood: You forgot about `export(PACKAGE)` command flow, which "publishes" the package from the build tree, so it can be found with `find_package()`.